# Current year, 'now' is undefined in Pelican template

Tags: jinja2, pelican

I'm trying to display the current year in my footer in Pelican website. My understanding is that Pelican uses Jinja2 template.

In my *footer.html* I use:

```
<span>{{ now().year }}</span>
```

And I use it in my *base.html* as

```
{% include 'footer.html' %}
```

But when I generate the page I've got the error

> Undefined Error: 'now' is undefined

And I cannot find the reason.

Is there any trick/setting/plugin I need to use this?

Comment: Nope, there is no date support in Jinja, sadly. Related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54072879/how-to-insert-the-current-date-with-jinja2

Comment: After a second look at this, I found some inside inside Pelican specifically, there is a `strftime` extra Jinja filter but you’ll still need to get the date from somewhere and that includes modifying the Python configuration file of the site. Would a solution doing this still be of interest to you?

Comment: Thank you for checking that for me! Yes, I can modify the config. Could you add the answer? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelican provides a `strftime` extra filter to Jinja, that works exactly like Python's `strftime`.

Here are the sources of this finding:

1. [this line from their code base](https://github.com/getpelican/pelican/blob/960aee5907aac2a732ac14b97e026374ad1d07de/pelican/generators.py#L93)
2. [and this page of documentation](https://docs.getpelican.com/en/4.8.0/themes.html#date-formatting)

---

This said, you will need a `datetime` object to use this filter on.

The later can be obtained by modifying your configuration file, *pelicanconf.py*, adding those two lines

```py
from datetime import datetime
NOW = datetime.now()

## Mind that:
##   All the setting identifiers must be set in all-caps, 
##   otherwise they will not be processed.
## @see https://docs.getpelican.com/en/latest/settings.html#settings
```

Now, in your template, you can start using this newly created `NOW` variable and apply the [`strftime` format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes), which means that you want `%Y` for the year:

```
{{ NOW | strftime('%Y') }}
```

Comment: Works like a dream, thank you!